# react-navigation v5 (next): Navigating to nested Child screen from the Child screen of different Parent

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using react-navigation v5 (next):

High Level Question: Navigating to nested Child screen from the Child screen of different Parent.

Here is my root navigator

```js
export const AppNavigator = (props): React.ReactElement => (
   <Stack.Navigator {...props} headerMode='none' mode={'modal'}>
      <Stack.Screen name={AppRoute.AUTH} component={AuthNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name={AppRoute.HOME} component={HomeNavigator} />
   </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

Here is my AuthNavigator:

```js
export const AuthNavigator = (): React.ReactElement => (
   <Stack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
      <Stack.Screen name={AppRoute.SIGN_IN} component={SignInScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={AppRoute.LOG_OUT} component={LogOutScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={AppRoute.SIGN_UP} component={SignUpScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
         name={AppRoute.RESET_PASSWORD}
         component={ResetPasswordScreen}
      />
   </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

From within a page in `HomeNavigator` I want to navigate directly to the `LogOutScreen`/`AppRoute.LOG_OUT`.

I can call `navigate(AppRoute.AUTH)` but if I call `navigate(AppRoute.LOG_OUT)` it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```js
// Navigate to 'AppRoute.LOG_OUT' inside 'AppRoute.AUTH'
navigation.navigate(AppRoute.AUTH, { screen: AppRoute.LOG_OUT });
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/next/nesting-navigators.html#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator